# creating a compound index in c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, compound-index

I want to create a compound index where one key should be in ascending, the second key in descending order.

How can I do this?

I have a string containing the property names the user selected.

```
collection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys.Descending(selectedProperties[0]),
                IndexKeys.Ascending(selectedProperties[1])),
IndexOptions.......
```

does not work

Answer (score 15):

In v2.x of the driver they completely changed the API so currently the way to create a compound index asynchronously (which is prefered) is:

```
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(
    Builders<Hamster>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Name).Descending(_ => _.Age),
    new CreateIndexOptions { Background = true });
```

And synchronously:

```
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(
    Builders<Hamster>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Name).Descending(_ => _.Age),
    new CreateIndexOptions { Sparse = true });
```

Comment: How to create more than one indexes in  v2.3 ( Indexes.CreateMany())?

Comment: what exactly the "Background=true" option does here?

Answer (score 11):

Here's one way:

```
var keys = new IndexKeysBuilder();

keys.Ascending(keyName1);
keys.Descending(keyName2);

var options = new IndexOptionsBuilder();
options.SetSparse(true);
options.SetUnique(false);
collection.EnsureIndex(keys, options);
```

Answer (score 6):

`EnsureIndex` is now obsolete, so `CreateIndex` should be used instead. There are also static builder classes the support fluent usage: `IndexKeys` and `IndexOptions`.

So the cleanest option is:

```
collection.CreateIndex(
    IndexKeys.Ascending(keyName1).Descending(keyName2),
    IndexOptions.SetSparse(true).SetUnique(false));
```

And for a generic type-safe option:

```
collection.CreateIndex(
    IndexKeys<Document>.Ascending(d => d.Property1).Descending(d => d.Property2),
    IndexOptions.SetSparse(true).SetUnique(false));
```

Answer (score -1):

CreateIndex with

```
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<T>(keys.Ascending(x => x.Property1).Ascending(x=>x.Property2));
                
collection.Indexes.CreateOne(indexModel);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, aadreja. could you please add some text to explain why this is the best answer, or how it works?

Comment: @SashaKondrashov - collection.CreateIndex with index keys is obsolete (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoIndexManager_1_CreateOne_2.htm).